# Coq: Proving conat is either finite or infinite

Tags: coq, theorem-proving, coinduction

I have a definition of `conat` which can represent both finite and infinite values, a conversion from `nat`, a definition of infinity, and a bisimulation relation:

```
CoInductive conat : Set := O' | S' (n : conat).

Fixpoint toCo (n : nat) : conat := match n with
  | O => O'
  | S n' => S' (toCo n') end.

CoFixpoint inf : conat := S' inf.

CoInductive bisim : conat -> conat -> Prop :=
  | OO : bisim O' O'
  | SS : forall n m : conat, bisim n m -> bisim (S' n) (S' m).

Notation "x == y" := (bisim x y) (at level 70).
```

I want to prove that `conat` is either finite or infinite (I'm not 100% sure that this is the correct formulation):

```
(* This is the goal *)
Theorem fin_or_inf : forall n : conat, (exists m : nat, toCo m == n) \/ (n == inf).
```

I couldn't prove it so far, but I could prove another statement that, if a `conat` is not finite, it is infinite (again, not 100% sure about the formulation):

```
(* I have a proof for this *)
Theorem not_fin_then_inf : forall n : conat, ~ (exists m : nat, toCo m == n) -> (n == inf).
```

I have no idea how to go from `not_fin_then_inf` to `fin_or_inf` though.

1. **Is my definition of `fin_or_inf` correct?**
2. **Can I prove `fin_or_inf`, either using `not_fin_then_inf` or not using it?**

Also, I found that bridging the gap between the two theorems involves decidability of bisimulation (or extension thereof). I think the decidability theorem could be stated as

```
Lemma bisim_dec : forall n m : conat, n == m \/ ~ (n == m).
```

3. **Can I prove `bisim_dec` or any similar statement on bisimulation?**

---

#### Edit

The original motivation to prove "either finite or infinite" was to prove commutativity and associativity of `coplus`:

```
CoFixpoint coplus (n m : conat) := match n with
  | O' => m
  | S' n' => S' (coplus n' m)
end.
Notation "x ~+ y" := (coplus x y) (at level 50, left associativity).

Theorem coplus_comm : forall n m, n ~+ m == m ~+ n.
Theorem coplus_assoc : forall n m p, n ~+ m ~+ p == n ~+ (m ~+ p).
```

Going through the same way as `nat`'s `+` does not work because it requires transitivity of `==` with a lemma analogous to `plus_n_Sm`, which makes the cofix call unguarded. Otherwise, I have to destruct both `n` and `m`, and then I'm stuck at the goal `n ~+ S' m == m ~+ S' n`.

If I choose an alternative definition of `coplus`:

```
CoFixpoint coplus (n m : conat) := match n, m with
  | O', O' => O'
  | O', S' m' => S' m'
  | S' n', O' => S' n'
  | S' n', S' m' => S' (S' (coplus n' m'))
end.
```

Then `coplus_comm` is easy, but `coplus_assoc` becomes near-impossible to prove instead.

4. **Can I indeed prove `coplus_comm` with the first definition of `coplus`, or `coplus_assoc` with the second?**

Comment: You can't. It's outside of the theory of Coq. You can probably prove it if you assume LPO (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_principle_of_omniscience).

Comment: @gallais Could you ellaborate? (Or point to some resources which does)

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay All of the functions defined in CIC have to be continuous. In the context of codata, it means that you may only consume a finite amount of an input before you output at least one bit of information (i.e. for any function `f` from `conat` to `Bool` there is a natural number `n` such that any two conats that agree for their first `n` constructors will be mapped to the same value by `f`). This is incompatible with a function being able to tell whether a conat is finite or not.